# Concatenating two XML files using JavaScript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, dom

I have been tasked with splitting an XML file into two parts for ease of editing.

But all the existing codebase is designed to treat it as a single file.

As a middle ground (due to a paucity of time) I decided to split the files, but simply concatenate the split files by using the following code

```
    var xmlDoc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","distributome-relations.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    xmlhttp=createAjaxRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","distributome-references.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlDoc+xmlhttp.responseXML;
            try{
        DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    }catch(error){
        DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.childNodes;
    }
```

Which doesn't seem to work while the original code

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Distributome.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (!xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement && xmlhttp.responseStream)
        xmlhttp.responseXML.load(xmlhttp.responseStream);
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    try{
        DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    }catch(error){
        DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.childNodes;
    }
```

Works perfectly fine.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

I have simply split the file

http://www.distributome.avinashc.com/avinash/Distributome.xml into

http://www.distributome.avinashc.com/avinash/distributome-relations.xml and 
http://www.distributome.avinashc.com/avinash/distributome-references.xml

The last two files will appear improperly formatted because only a simple concatenation of the two files is expected to be a valid XML document.

I suspect that this is due to the use of the responseXML method and that I should use an alternate method.

Is there a better way to do this. I would welcome any suggestions, and of course - answers to my original question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you explained what `doesn't seem to work` translates to but from a quick look at your code I can tell that **you are trying to concatenate two [`DOM Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) objects using `+`**. This line:

```
xmlDoc = xmlDoc + xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

The `responseXML` property of the XHR doesn't return a string like you seem to expect (btw, concatenating two XML files like that would very likely result into a not well formed XML anyway). The second example treats it properly for what it is - the DOM Document object.

You can read more about `responseXML` [over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest). Pay attention to the note about the `Content-Type` and how you might need to use the `overrideMimeType()` on your XHR to make it believe it received an XML from the server if the server didn't set the header properly.

To do your concatenation in the XML-aware fashion you would need to grab the root node from the second document ([`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement)), import it into the first document using the [`importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode) and then append it as a child node where you want it to be using [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Comment: I see. 

Would it be valid to scan the files as text, concatenate it and treat the string as an XML object?

Basically xmlDoc is not a valid XML object - which now seems obvious given your explanation.

I will look into the documentation and hopefully clear things up.

Comment: well, you can do that too. just make sure you add the second document into the right place in the first document. if it carries `<?xml` or a  `<!DOCTYPE` you would need to also parse that out. In general, I would recommend to stay XML-aware to make sure you end up with the XML per se, but you sure possible to get away with manipulating strings. Just more messy :) and btw, if the answer helped you or answered your question then please consider upvoting/accepting it