# Pentaho data integration: merge two xml files into one

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, pentaho

How to merge two xml files into one with Pentaho data integration?
The following are my 2 xml files:

XML file 1:

```
<Root>
    <OLD>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </OLD>
     <OLD>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </OLD>
<Root>
```

Xml file 2:

```
<Root>
    <NEW>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </NEW>
    <NEW>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </NEW>
<Root>
```

Both the files having same nodes.
expected Output file:

```
<Root>
    <OLD>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </OLD>
    <OLD>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </OLD>
     <NEW>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </NEW>
    <NEW>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
            <Node> </Node>
     </NEW>
<Root>
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223203/kettle-append-xml-files-content

Comment: are you sure that we able to do using XML join step ?? (i didn't find full answer in your link )

Comment: just want to emphasize the fact that pentaho does not concatenate xml files. :)

Comment: so you want to use that pentaho component in which you write javascript code, maybe this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695294/concatenating-two-xml-files-using-javascipt-ajax

Comment: Problem has solved, i approached diff way !!! Thanks all.

Comment: you can post your fix as an answer to your question, maybe it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Question 2:

XML file.

```
<roots>
    <root>
    <text1>increased by</text1>
    <value1>10</value1>
    <text2>decreased by<text2>
    <value2>-7</value2>
    </root>
</roots>
```

Expected HTML output:

```
increased by 10 --(value 10 in green color)
decreased by -7 -- (value -7 in red color)
```

and Iam trying to implement XSLT below way...

```
<xsl:template match="value1">
<xsl:if test="value1 >= 0">
     <font color="green"><xsl:apply-templates/>/></font>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value1">
<xsl:if test="value1 < 0">
     <font color="red"><xsl:apply-templates/>/></font>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```